# Deal with huge forms in Spring

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc

I hope you can help me. I've tried to look for a solution to this problem or for a similar question here in StackOverflow but couldn't find any, so here it is.

We must develop a feature in which we will have a multi-page form. After filling all the pages of the form, the user will submit it. The problem is that the final submit will send many parameters (around 500), and we're afraid we may encounter problems with request size in many cases.

An initial approach would be having an object in session, which would be partially filled when the user navigates through the pages. I.e. when the user fills the fields in page 1, the object in session is partially filled with that data, and so on. That way, we wouldn't have to pass all the request parameters in every step and the final submit wouldn't have to send so many data. But we don't want to use this approach because we don't want to use the session to store data that are specific to a single functionality or bunch of pages.

Another approach would be saving data to a database after the user fills each page of the form, and retrieving it after the final submit so we can deal with the whole thing. Maybe we could do this, but it would delay the development of the project since it's not a trivial task.

I wonder if there's a better approach to handle this. Maybe using @Cacheable in some intelligent way, maybe using Spring WebFlow (which I've never worked with), maybe other alternatives I can't think of. Is there any strategy or technology I could use for this? Currently we are working with Spring 3.2. We are using jQuery as well, just in case it's relevant.

Thank you.

Comment: If a site has 10,000 visitors then it should have fault tolernce - load balancing at DNS and web server, caches for resources (many ways from content providers to memcache) Even if you have a 500 field form for 1 user it would take 200KB, nowdays 80GB servers are used ... so long way to go to run out of memory. rather say code per standards and test with jmeter or other load testing tools - takes 2 weeks to learn and set up so plan for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing as answer as I would not fit into comment:

- There is no limit to request body size for POST requests. Only GET requests are limited (i.e. when parameters are sent via query parameters). No need to worry here.
- I don't understand why you don't want to use session ([@SessionAttributes](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and-session-attributes/)). Having multi-step forms is one of the use-case this was designed for I would say.
- Storing incomplete model objects in database is also a good approach as it is very close to REST principles. We have used this multiple times in our company.
- Spring WebFlow is also a good approach if you don't want to handle all the transitional logic yourself. However SWF is not that simple technology to learn and you should include that fact in your effort estimations.
- There is another approach, which I would say is becoming more and more popular: doing all the logic dynamically on a single webpage (e.g. via AngularJS or some [jQuery plugin](http://www.jquery-steps.com/)) and submit the result as a JSON object.

There is no definitive answer to your question without being very specific about your use-case and your application. And even with exhaustive description it is question about personal preference.

- The single dynamic page approach (e.g. AngularJS) would be good if your overall application architecture is going to be designed that way.
- Spring WebFlow would be nice if you are familiar with that technology or if you are planning on having more multi-step forms throughout the application (i.e. I would not go for SWF if I need to solve just one use-case with it).
- I would probably go for `@SessionAttributes` if I need to quickly solve a single multi-step form. There are some complexities connected to that (partial validation and partial binding namely)... so again this might not be the simplest approach in the end.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with storing things in session is that the application will have tens of thousands of users so there's a risk that there are too many data stored in session and that leads to performance problems. As for partial storing in a database, the problem is that this would require people outside our team, it's not a task that we can manage by ourselves and must be managed by database team, and these people are not available for new developments right now. SWF seems interesting since there will be more use cases like this in a future, so I'll have a look at it.

Comment: The Spring WebFlow would have the same issue... it stores data on session by default as well. http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/webflow/conversation/impl/SessionBindingConversationManager.html

Comment: Nope... asynchronous session attribute expiration is not possible. SWF can only expire old conversations when a new one is created (i.e. number of active conversations can be limited).

Comment: If you are really worried about the server performance, I would consider the single dynamic page approach. You can implement that easily with jQuery and some client side validation. A quick google gives also some interesting results - http://www.jquery-steps.com/ .

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot. That approach is really interesting, seems fast to be developed and easy to learn. I'll have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Webflow would handle your use case nicely through its flowScope.

Anyway, I you don't want to go through the pain of integrating its infrastructure only for that, the session attribute you mentioned will work perfectly and it's a correct approach. Just make sure you remove it when it's not neccesary anymore to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take a deeper look into SWF and see if it can meet our needs.